# is there a way to determine if R code is running on the client (laptop install) or on the server - in R server install

Tags: r, server, client

is there a way to determine if R code is running on the client (laptop install) or on the server - in R server install? One reason is to determine what email library to include to send email - since if running on linux VM then the email will go out differently than if sent from client side in corporate MS domain environment.

Thanks

Comment: Yes - that is it - I opted to .Platform$OS.type call that return "windows" or "unix" if run from linux RHEL 7 for example ...

Comment: Thanks for quick help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can query the hostname from within R:

```
> Sys.info()['nodename']
        nodename 
"U8002287-TPL-B"
```

https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-June/280773.html